# LTS22.04 - nVidia 515.65.01 enable wayland - proving impossible

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, gdm, wayland

I have migrated from Windows to Ubuntu on a Lenovo Legion 5 Pro laptop, I want to compare Wayland to X11 (scaling issues on my multi-monitor setup) but cannot get Wayland enabled. I've tried the two most common solutions:

1. Editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and uncommenting "WaylandEnable" setting it to "WaylandEnable=true"
2. Editing /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules and commenting out the line that says if nVidia driver version greater than 5.10 is detected then use X11

However, I find the system still resolutely uses X11, and (possibly because I have auto-login selected) I don't see a GDM screen where I have an option to switch.

Comment: My experience is that nvidia and Wayland don't work well together. I switched the desktop to the old Xorg, and it works well for me. (I think Xorg or x11 are different names of the same thing.) But I think we have different versions of nvidia hardware (problably newer than mine), and I don't know if the newest updates of software can manage the cooperation between nvidia and Wayland.

Comment: Thanks sudodus.  I have got this working by (in addition to the steps in my original post):  1.  disabling autologin for my user account.  2.  At the login screen, clicking on my user account and then using the gear icon that appears at the bottom right to select "Ubuntu on Wayland".  I would like to learn how to use Wayland when using auto-login, but that's a different question.  I haven't encountered any issues yet when using the nVidia 515.65.01 driver with Wayland, and it has given me more sensible scaling across my multi-monitor setup, so I will be sticking with Wayland going forwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and uncommenting "WaylandEnable" setting it to "WaylandEnable=true"
2. Editing /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules and commenting out the line that says if nVidia driver version greater than 5.10 is detected then use X11
3. disabling autologin for my user account.
4. At the login screen, clicking on my user account and then using the gear icon that appears at the bottom right to select "Ubuntu on Wayland".

It appears that having selected the "Ubuntu on Wayland" option once, it is selected as the default option on the next login, but I haven't yet tried re-enabling autologin to confirm that the login continues to use Wayland if I do this.

Comment: I was about to suggest your 4th step. I thought it should be enough. Wasn't it?

Comment: Hi Ictus, it was, but I didn't get the option of Wayland or the gear icon before I'd performed steps 1 to 3, and I'd hoped that items 1 and 2 would be enough for Wayland to be selected automatically without needing to disable auto-login.  It wasn't.  I'm guessing it's step 2 that has allowed Wayland to be an option on the GDM login screen, and then by manually selecting it I've got Wayland, but for anyone who's got auto-login enabled, the key bit of information is that they'll need to disable auto-login to get the option to switch on the gdm login screen.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)